# Setting a default query search at boot in Evernote

Tags: evernote

I'm really happy using Evernote but I have a problem. I have the necessity to get some sticky notes in there so when I open the software I'll already know what's gonna kill me today.
Since, as I understood it, Evernote 4.5.1 is missing a "Sticky Notes" function I wrote a simple query that gets a specific combination of tags that gets important notes.
What I want to do now is to set this search query to be the default behaviour of Evernote so when I open it, I have those notes.

Is there a way of doing that?